# Is there a survey that explores all the available Markov chain Monte Carlo methods?

Tags: monte-carlo, markov-process

I am interested in exploring the efficacy of various Monte Carlo methods.
I am aware of the Metropolis acceptance criterion, Hamiltonian Markov chains, Gibbs sampling, importance sampling, slice sampling etc. But, I guess that there are many more that I am not aware about. Can any one point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01148) is a fairly recent paper on Bayesian Computation methods in general.

Comment: Are you aware of mcmc methods for discrete distributions.?

Comment: That's a good follow up question. From what I've seen the HMC and Langevin stuff doesn't cater for discrete distributions. The Hamming Ball Sampler is an interesting one for complex binary distributions ( https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5456-hamming-ball-auxiliary-sampling-for-factorial-hidden-markov-models.pdf  ). Then there are variational inference methods (not MCMC) which have seen a lot of use lately.

Comment: Thanks.  There are also many references in the article suggested by greenparker on discrete distributions.

Comment: @Greenparker: thanks for pointing out our survey! This is however a short introduction to the field, focussing on MCMC methods. For a deeper entry, you could consult the [Handbook of MCMC](http://amzn.to/21tD62D).

Comment: The survey is brilliant though :).  Thanks

Comment: May [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00579) paper is interesting as well, even though it only deals with methods you have already mentioned.